# Side-by-Side Editor and preview

Tags: feature-request

More often than not when I write a question I want to see what the output would be while I'm writing the question

Since most of the world has gone to widescreen aspect ratios on their monitors, there is a ton of available space on the sides of the editor window, but when your question or answer gets long you wind up having to scroll up and down a lot to view what the output will look like when it is posted...which can get quite cumbersome when posting large batches of code which need formatting

What if we dynamically had the preview of the post show up next to the editor window instead of below it when there is enough space available from the web browser?  That way we can see what we are typing while we are typing it rather than having to scroll up and down?  Seems like a simple enough change that would make a lot of our lives easier...

this has probably been brought up before, so feel free to close this if you already have thought of this and turned the idea down

Answer (score 2):

Well, this isn't a side-by-side preview, but it's close enough:

[Dude, where's my cursor?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3894/dude-wheres-my-cursor)

This puts a scrollable window on the preview, and makes it so that the area you're typing in is always in the preview.

Comment: That is nice, and a good start in the right direction, but more of the issue is that when you are working with large amounts of code on Stack Overflow (often times of which the code wraps onto several lines if it is really wide) you wind up having to expand the editor window height which gets rid of even more preview window space...seems like it would be easier if it were native to the stack exchange layout as well